SonarLint cannot find Git repo
I have SonarQube installed in Eclipse.
The SonarLint console log says it cannot connect to the git repository for my project even though I cloned the project from an SVN repo
How do I get SonarLint/SonarQube to recognize the Git repos?

SonarLint does not recognize SVN repositories and only supports Git repositories. I recommend reaching out to them directly on their Community forum about this, although it should not prevent you from using SonarLint.

The documentation says otherwise: "Subversion integration is supported out of the box for Subversion 1.6 to 1.9.x.".

This is the documentation of SonarQube Server, OP is asking about SonarQube for IDE (formerly known as SonarLint)

You right: "SonarLint for Eclipse only supports Git". Thanks for the clarification!
